# Is the bump edit a useful feature?

Tags: discussion

I was browsing active questions today and [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/182185/why-has-a-players-castle-became-nothing-but-ruin) question which was asked and answered by the same person back in 2014 appeared at the top of the queue.  It doesn't appear to be popular at all, with less than 200 views.  This despite the fact that the question has been "bumped" by "Community" more than 5 times.

As explained below, the Community bot will periodically bump questions that have no upvoted and/or accepted answers.

### Do we feel that this is a useful feature?

[image: Screenshot showing edit history for question, bumped by community user repeatedly.]

Comment: See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean when Community is shown as the last activity on a question?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2987/what-does-it-mean-when-community-is-shown-as-the-last-activity-on-a-question)

Answer (score 5):

It is a regular thing that happens to questions that do not have an answer marked as accepted. It is part of the [Community Bot's](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) job. It is helpful because it brings older questions that don't have an accepted answer and no upvoted to the top where users that might know the answer to it see it and can provide an answer. If you sort questions by active, you will see questions sorted by most recent activity and the bump pushes them to the top of that list.

Comment: Is it for questions without an accepted answer? I thought it was questions with no accepted answer AND no positive score answers.

Comment: @Vemonus yea,i think your right, i missed that part

Comment: @Vemonus That is good to know.  The answer on this particular question had 0 votes, which explains things.  I up-voted the answer, so hopefully we won't see it again.  :)

Comment: @Lumberjack - note that you should only upvote answers you think are useful. There's nothing wrong with the occasional bumped post, it helps the OP in that they might finally get an answer, and it helps the site, because we optimise for getting answers to questions - we wouldn't be much of a Q&A site if we didn't. :-) (Psst, it also makes it easier to find questions with which to earn the silver 'Necromancer' badge! ;-) )